# Why navigator onchange doesn't work on cellphones?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code :

```
 const camPerm = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "camera" });
  vTrack.onended = () => console.log('ENDED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
  camPerm.onchange = () => {
   console.log('works')
  };
```

Which works well with any pc and yet it is not triggered on cellphones ( both `onchange` and `onended` ). How can I listen to permission changes on cellphones and act upon user removing camera permission on my app?

Comment: Can you please specify what browser you are using to test this on mobile ?

Comment: Chrome and Safari and Opera all have failed me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `vTrack.onended` is, but you can do this with `PermissionStatus` and listing for the change in the state IE `PermissionStatus.state`

```
navigator.permissions
   .query({ name: "camera" })
   .then((permissionStatus) => {
        console.log(`camera is set to ${permissionStatus.state}`);
    permissionStatus.onchange = () => {
       console.log(
           `the camera permissions have been changed: ${permissionStatus.state}`
       );
};
```

Comment: Works well on my pc but onchange is not triggered on my iphone with Chrome, I am baffeled.

Comment: @Hypothesis have you tried multiple devices?  I have never had an issue using this with any of my web apps.   Confirmed working with iPhone 11 running iOS.  Also if you view the docs. [iOS and Chrome is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus)

Comment: Also looking at the Chrome releases make sure to look at the version numbers and make sure your device's Chrome is up to date.

Comment: It didn't work and I ended up using an unorthodox way as such :  const vTrack = read.stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        setInterval(async () => {
          const camPerm = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "camera" });
          camPerm.state !== 'granted' && (write.page = 'CAMMICOFF')
        }, 5000);